# Asp image button OnClientClick javascript(id)

Tags: c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I have dataGrid and LinkButton with javascript,
how to get ID for MessageSend function?

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton ID="MessageButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:void(MessageSend(SomeID))"  ImageUrl="Header.gif"/>
</ItemTemplate>

<asp:BoundColumn Visible="True" DataField="SomeID" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="ID"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this way

```
function MessageSend(sender) {
    // do whatever with the input
}
```

and in the `OnClientClick` use `javascript:MessageSend(this);`

The result is you get the sender element in your routine.